# Get failure reason from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a declarative pipeline for Jenkins. In my `post` section, I am using `slackSend` to notify my team that the build is broken. I'd like to include the failure reason. Is this available in `env` or `currentBuild` or something else? I haven't seen anything in the documentation, but seems like a common use case

I've seen some posts about using `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10)` and that works, but it is just filled with way too much information. I need to zero in on the actual exception

Comment: did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736594/get-error-reason-in-jenkinsfile-failure

Comment: That's a decent start, but only provides the failure stage not reason/exception

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to [use a `catchError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44160223/6309) or at least [a `try/catch`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control).
Then, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38905154/6309), you can get the error message: `String error = "${e}";`

Regarding catchError, you would wrap every step that can potentially fail into a `catchError` function. If an error occurs, it will set `build.result` to FAILURE, and *continue* the build.

See [`catchError`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-catcherror-code-catch-error-and-set-build-result), which points out that only the `try/catch` approach might be useful to catch the actual error `e` (and its string).
You might then add that error string to a global variable, that your `post` step could then access.
That would be less verbose and/or more precise than `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Since I'm using a declarative pipeline, do I need to wrap every step of every stage in a `script { try { ... } catch(e) { ... } } `?

Comment: @MikeB Yes, although declarative might not be compatible with try/catch: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44003788/6309

Comment: If you can catch the error within a step, you can use script to assign a variable: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/094fa9f02f95dfc0c7d798c7e83b8d38caae0a65/declarative-examples/simple-examples/postUnstable.groovy

Comment: Ok yeah you are right. Unfortunately, the exception I got wasn't very helpful: `hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1`

Comment: @MikeB Not helpful indeed! I am looking at https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/find/master, looking for "Post" and see how this is implemented.

Comment: @MikeB Just to be sure, did that catched error have a cause (a chained error which might say more about its origin)?

Comment: `e.cause` is null

Comment: @MikeB, @VonC: Has it been figured out how to get a meaningful error message out of a stage's thrown Exception? We are also only ever getting `hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1`...

Comment: @GoingBananas I have not for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way of invoking the curl command, this is what i used in my bash script recently.

```
full_error_msg=$(curl -s -k -X GET $url/job/$job_name/lastBuild/consoleText 2> /dev/null | tac | grep Error | head -n 2 | tr -d '\n')
```

Since the error message usually comes at the end of the build, i use tac command to flip the output, grep for the line containing 'Error', and head the next two lines removing the carriage return between these two Error lines.

Comment: This is a very unreliable aproach.