# Send Jenkins error log in email (can't extract the error part of log)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, error-log, email-ext

I need to extract the part of the jenkins log that contains just the error description and stack trace so that I can send it in an email (which I do using the jenkins email ext plugin in the pipeline).

For e.g., in the following log snippet, I would need all lines after "org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity ..."

```
    ...
    Sending build end EMAIL
    [Pipeline] echo
    Build Number: 218
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Actionable getAction java.lang.Class. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Actionable getAction java.lang.Class
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
        at WorkflowScript.sendBuildEmail(WorkflowScript:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:124)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:131)
        at
        ...
```

How can I achieve this? I'll appreciate any help

This is my pipeline structure:

```
       pipeline {
         agent {...} 
         environment {...}
         stages {...}
         post {...}
       }
```

Comment: You could try exporting the error log outside the UI and mail it later with another task: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MakinglogsavailableoutsideofthewebUI

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to wrap your whole pipeline script in a `try`/`catch` block and then sending an email using the [`mail` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#mail-mail) in the `catch` block. Here's how I would write it:

```
try {

    // your pipeline code
    // ...

} catch (e) {
    mail subject: "${env.JOB_NAME}#${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Failed",
         body: """
 Build: ${env.BUILD_URL}

 Error message: 
 ${e.getMessage()}

 Stack Trace:
 ${e.getStackTrace().join('\n')}
         """,
         to: 'me@email.com'

    throw e // rethrow the error so that it gets printed in the job log, and so the job fails
}
```

You will definitely need to approve `getStackTrace` as a "secure" method and you might have to do the same for `getMessage`.

Something to keep in mind is that this try/catch will not catch 'No such DSL method ' errors, which seems to be not a bug according to [JENKINS-45469](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45469).

If you're interested in more complicated email behavior, you can alo checkout the [extended email plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/).

Comment: For so long, I've been trying to use try-catch in a part of my pipeline where I was calling a non-existent method just to test, and the catch block was not executing. It was just giving me the 'No such DSL method' error and failing the build. Now I know why. Thanks! I'll try testing with other types of errors and see if it works out.

Comment: Is there a way I can use the try-catch on just the 'stages' part, rather than the entire pipeline?

Comment: Can you give me an example of your pipeline? Is it declarative pipeline?

Comment: Yes it is, I added pipeline structure in post above

Comment: I don't think declarative pipeline allows you to rus try/catch outside a script block (which you can add inside a step), nor does it expose the failures cause through a function or variable afaik. You can look at this post for some suggestions on what you could do instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843211/get-failure-reason-from-jenkins-pipeline
but if you want to do something a little more complicated you could change your pipeline job to not be declarative.